# Passing a div class into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to pass the class of a div into a javascript function? I am using square space so I cannot add an id to the div, but I can get it to work with div's that do have id's. Also, I already have loaded the jquery.

This is what I am thinking so far, thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhideme(arg) {
    $(arg).slideDown()
}

function clickme(arg1, arg2) {
    unhideme(arg1);
    unhideme(arg2);
    //other stuff
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#myid{
display:none
}
.klass{
display:none
}
</style>

<form><input type="submit" onclick="clickme('#myid','.klass')">
<div id="myid"></div>
<div class="klass"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What isn't working? Help us out here. What is your actual question?

Comment: Sorry, the div with the id slides down like its supposed to, but the div with the class doesn't slide down.

Comment: There's a typo.. not sure if that's in your real code: `,/div>`

Comment: You are missing a `<` here `<div class="klass">,/div>`

Comment: unfortunately that wasn't in my real code...

Comment: The divs have no content. How can you tell they're not sliding down?

Comment: They do in my real code.

Comment: Is this the correct way to pass a class as an argument into a function? Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your real code. Possible that your form is submitting before the animation can occur. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WSxws/

Comment: @tmattimore: Yeah, this should be fine.

Comment: Is that submit button reloading the page causing the elements to be hidden again?

Comment: Here's a working fiddle. I did have to prevent the form from submitting: http://jsfiddle.net/Sy6ME/

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for all the quick responses. I think the issue is that I am trying to hide a part of the page that I created with the squarespace form editor, and then found the class name by using inspect. I ended up finding another div enclosing the one I would like to hide that has an id.

Comment: In order to point at a div inside of another div using classes, would I have to pass .klass1.klass2 into the argument?

Comment: Yes, but there has to be space between them: `.klass1 .klass2`. Without space you would search for an element with both classes.

Comment: @tmattimore you should probably accept the answer if you forgot :)

Comment: for everyone that answered, thank you. realizing i never closed this a year ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function unhideme(classname) {
  $(classname).slideDown();
}

function clickme(classname) {
  unhideme(classname);
}
</script>
<style>
.klass {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<form>
  <input type="submit" onclick="clickme('.klass');return false;">
  <div class="klass">testdown</div>
</form>
```